# MySQL - Renaming table named "TABLE 12"

Tags: mysql, sql, table-rename

I'm trying to pass my problem... namely I can't rename my table named "TABLE 12" which was imported. I got a response:

```
#1064 - You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near ''TABLE 12' TO categories' at line 1
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use ` instead of ' to quote database/table/field-names in MySQL.
e.g.:

```
RENAME TABLE `TABLE 12` TO `categories`
```

Answer (score 1):

Use backticks on system related objects.

Assuming your table name is `TABLE 12`:

```
RENAME TABLE `TABLE 12` TO `categories`
```

Assuming your table name is `12`:

```
RENAME TABLE `12` TO `categories`
```

[Documentation](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/rename-table.html)

Answer (score 0):

Try using the backtick symbol (`) instead of quotes (').

```
RENAME TABLE `TABLE 12` TO `Categories`
```